# data retrive using self join in table

Tags: sql, self-join

I am using self join to fetch data

Table name MyInfo:

```
+------+------+
| NAME | CITY |
+------+------+
|  a   | null |
|  b   | null |
| null |  c   |
| null |  d   |
+------+------+
```

I want output as

```
+------+------+
| NAME | CITY |
+------+------+
|  a   |  c   |
|  b   |  d   |
+------+------+
```

I tried : I used self join but could not get above result.

I used union all too but didn't get output.

Prob : I am able to only display either name or city field, can I get as above output.
any clue or any suggestion can help me.

Comment: Hi, please provide more details. Like your table structure and what you have tried yet

Comment: please give ur table details as well and more detail

Comment: You should edit the question and provide sample data and expected results.  These should be as text -- the images are too small to read.  You can use the "{}" button to format the text, or just put four spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: how do you know that name A can be mapped with City C, and B with D. Can't the mapping be A with D and B with C too? Are you certain you understand the concepts of RDBMS well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select * from (select top 1  * from 
(select t2.NAME ,t1.CITY from tel t1,tel t2
where t2.NAME !=t1.CITY)m union 
select top 1  * from  (select t2.NAME ,t1.CITY
from tel t1,tel t2  where t2.NAME !=t1.CITY
)m order by m.NAME desc,m.CITY desc)A
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Vinoth_S and all for your valuable feedback.